# Prove that the set of positive integers can be expressed as a countably infinite union of disjoint countably infinite sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $\mathbb Z^+$ of positive integers. Prove that $\mathbb Z^+$ can be expressed as a countably infinite union of disjoint countably infinite sets.

I know that countably infinite sets means it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$ (the set of natural numbers).

However, I am not sure how to go about proving this.

Comment: Hint: Consider the rational numbers, which have the same cardinality as the integers.

Comment: Strictly countably infinite? Or is finite cardinality acceptable too?

Comment: @Cameron Williams- Strictly countably infinite

Answer (score 1):

An easy and cool aproach to this question is using the infinity of the prime numbers.

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of prime numbers. For each $p \in \mathbb{P}$ consider $A_{p} = \lbrace p^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\rbrace $ which is an countably infinite set. Consider $ R = \mathbb{Z^{+}}$\ $ \bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{P}}A_{p}$ which is an countably infinite set.

You have that $\mathbb{Z^{+}}= \bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{P}}A_{p} \cup R$ so you have expressed $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ as a countably infinite union of disjoint countably infinite sets.

Comment: Is there a way I can go about doing this proof for an abstract case?

Comment: What do you mean by abstract case?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one possible solution is
$$ \begin{matrix}
      1 &  2 &  4 &  7 & \cdots \\
      3 &  5 &  8 & 12 & \cdots \\
      6 &  9 & 13 & 18 & \cdots \\
     10 & 14 & 19 & 26 & \cdots \\
    \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots
\end{matrix}$$
This infinite two dimensional array is given by two
integer sequences. Namely,
[OEIS sequence A002260](https://oeis.org/A002260)
and [OEIS sequence A004736](https://oeis.org/A004736).
Each positive integer $\,n\,$ appears exactly once in row
number $\,t_1(n)\,$ and column number $\,t_2(n).\,$
The formulas for these functions are
$$ t_1(n) := n - C(\lfloor 1/2+\sqrt{2n}\rfloor,2) $$
and
$$ t_2(n) := C(\lfloor 3/2+\sqrt{2n}\rfloor,2) $$
where $\, C(n,2) := n(n-1)/2.\,$
Each row  represents a countably
infinite set of  positive integers and there
are a countably infinite set of rows. The positive integer
in row $\,n\,$ and column $\,k\,$ is
$$ T(n,k) := C(n+k-1,2)+n. $$ It needs to be proven
that $\, T(t_1(n),t_2(n)) = n\,$ for all positive integer
$\,n\,$ and then this implies that the rows are disjoint
and hence their union is all positive integers.